# Delete Contacts Failing

Tags: error, contact, error-messages, delete, npsp

I am pretty new to Salesforce and have been tasked with deleting all data and starting new. As I understand it, the best/only way to do this is to use the Data Loader or the Mass Delete in the web app.

Regardless of which method I choose, I receive an error message when trying to delete Contacts. I even get the message when on a particular contact and click "Delete" as a regular user would. All three methods produce the following error which I don't know how to investigate:

> An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again. npsp.TDTM_Contact: execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0G24000002SRPfEAO; first error: ENTITY_IS_DELETED, entity is deleted: [] (npsp)

Comment: Have you got an ApexTrigger being fired on delete? You may be hardcoding an ID within this trigger and that would be the reason why you see this error. Very hard to determine exactly why you are seeing this without reviewing any code.

Comment: Looks like there are some (I didn't even know those existed...) in an installed package called "RollupHelper" - not sure how to view the code for them, though.

Comment: I have found some useful info for you on [Andrew Fawcetts Github](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/issues/39#issuecomment-239904712). Looks to be a known bug and you may need to upgrade?